# Where can I find reliable information on long-distance hiking trails?

Tags: hiking, portugal

I have never planned a hiking holiday myself but have always walked along. This year we are planning to walk a long-distance trail like the Fischermenstrail (ROTA VICENTINA) in Portugal. Where can I find reliable information on which months the weather is best for hiking and how crowded this trail is? We want to walk on a somewhat quieter path.

So specifically, I'm not interested in the route but in collected reports of experiences and also soft parameters such as how warm it is at a certain time of year:D

Comment: Wouldn't a good start be one of the many hiking apps? Alltrails and Wikiloc come to mind.

Comment: For long-distrance trails in the UK, I usually find books the best source of information, but other countries may be different.

Comment: Fischermannsweg is a German word. Maybe this specific trail in Portugal does have a German name but otherwise I would assume searching for the English or Portugese name of the trail should give much more information.

Comment: Sry  i didnt noticed it. Thanks a lot